# Best way to store year/week in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to store year/week into a date data type?

If not what is the best way to store 2021/32 (year/week)?

Comment: `year`, `week` or `year`/`week` ? Depends why you store it (what kind of operations are needed). From a date, you can extract the week or the year. So the best is to NOT store it :-D (my $0.02)

Comment: @azbarcea I am aware you can extract it. But I get the data as year/week (when the product was manufactured). I was trying to avoid separate rows for date, year and week.

Comment: Then (as well as I see @sqlpro provided his update too), you have `YYYY-mm-dd` representing the first day of the week or 2 columns: `yyyy` and `week`. Either way, the decision rests upon what kind of operations/computing/relations you need afterwards. (again my $0,02).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want performances, the only way is to store the date of the first day of all weeks. Then add a view to compute the last day of the weeks and perhaps another view with all days (7) of the weeks.

```
CREATE TABLE T_WEEKS
(WKS_START_DATE DATE PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE VIEW T_WEEKS_INTERVAL
AS
SELECT WKS_START_DATE, WKS_START_DATE + INTERVAL '7 DAYS' AS WKS_END_DATE
FROM   T_WEEKS;

CREATE VIEW T_WEEKS_DATE
AS
WITH RECURSIVE T AS
(
SELECT WKS_START_DATE, WKS_START_DATE AS WKS_DATE
FROM   T_WEEKS

UNION ALL

SELECT T.WKS_START_DATE, CAST(T.WKS_START_DATE + INTERVAL '1 DAY' AS DATE) AS WKS_DATE
FROM   T_WEEKS AS W
       JOIN T ON W.WKS_START_DATE = T.WKS_START_DATE
WHERE  (T.WKS_DATE::DATE - T.WKS_START_DATE::DATE) < 7
)
SELECT * 
FROM   T;
```

Comment: The view T_WEEKS_DATE can be done way more efficiently using a cross join with `generate_series()`

Comment: yes ! @a_horse_with_no_name. But I try to give SQL code to be comptible for all DBMS or ISO SQL language... But ::DATE is no ISO nor compatible...